# Is "something" plural or singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

Which one is right?

> Something that is not working
>
> Something that are not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is a pronoun, which is analogous to "a thing", that is an indefinite pronoun. "A/an" is the Old English for "one" and one implies singularity.

Thus,

**I found a thing that wasn't working.**

**I found something that wasn't working.**

are the same in meaning, but 'something' is the commonly used version.

To pluralise your sentence, I would say: 
*"Some things that are not working."*

"Some things" is not a pronoun, thus the words are kept separate.

A = one

Some = more than one/indefinite article for mass nouns (e.g. "I want *some* milk", as milk is uncountable).

A thing = singular

Some things = plural

But when "some" is attached to -body, -where, -thing, -time, or -one,
(as in somebody, somewhere, something, sometime, someone) is *always* denotes a singular unspecified thing. There are no plurals for the pronouns somebody, something, and someone. Somewhere and sometime are adverbs, also denoting an unspecified place or time respectively.

Answer (score 1):

**Something** is referred to in the *singular*, for example:

- Something that does not work
- Something that is not working

Answer (score 1):

> Something that is not working.

`Something` is singular. Thus, the second sentence is incorrect as the verb `are` is the plural form.